# How to setState to answer from APi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Im trying to setState to response from Api onClick. Status got update but not when im clicking for first time, with second click, yes it does update.

```
     fetch(URL)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              recipesList: res
            });
          });
    console.log(this.state.recipesList);


  };
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: fetch is asynchronous, your `console.log` statement is being called before fetch is even returned. Put the `console.log` inside the `.then`. But be careful setState is also asynchronous! add a callback in setState and then put your console.log inside that

Comment: Your first question was answered. Try to not edit in another question. Please just ask another new question

Comment: shall I do it now ? Sorry im pretty new in stackoverflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56368443/9672457

Answer (score 5):

`setState()` is asynchronous. This means that React will choose when is the right time to update the state, which is probably not when you are doing `console.log()`.

Use `console.log()` on the `setState` callback, so when the state changes, your function is executed:

```
fetch(URL)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => {
       this.setState({
          recipesList: res
       },()=>{//setState callback.
          console.log(this.state.recipesList);
       });
    });
```

#### Use the fetch function in componentWillMount()

This is due to ReactJS lifecycle. If you execute the function inside `componentWillMount` it won't cause a second [render](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html#referencing-context-in-lifecycle-methods):

```
class yourComponent extends React.Component{

  state = {
     recipesList: []
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    fetch(URL)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(res => {
         this.setState({
            recipesList: res
         },()=>{//setState callback.
            console.log(this.state.recipesList);
         });
      });
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

> If you used `fetch` inside `componentWillMount()`, you can:

#### Render from map directly to render.

In your render method, use the map function like this:

```
render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="contentWrapper">
          {
             this.state.recipesList.map(item => {
               return (
                  <div className="recispesList">
                     <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                  </div>
               );
             })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It works this way, console.log shows updated state but now I want to map this.state. recipesList but I cant because state is still not updated.

Comment: @PawełDoliński You should've included that in your question. Feel free to edit and comment here again when you did so I get notified and give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: Is it better now ?

Comment: @PawełDoliński edited my answer too. Take a look and tell me if that solves your issue completely now.

Comment: I will add another question because I was not that clear what Im trying to do

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide full code but from this piece I see that `console.log(this.state.recipesList);` is outside of promise chain.

Because `fetch()` is asynchronous than `console.log(this.state.recipesList);` will be executed before 

`this.setState({
  recipesList: res
});`

Put your `console.log()` into callback of `this.setState()` which will be executed after state update.

```
fetch(URL)
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      recipesList: res
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.recipesList);
    }); 
 });
```

Comment: this.setState is also asynchronous, so this may not work.